# How to correctly react on file change

Tags: c#, file, vsix, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a Visual Studio editor plugin. I'd like the editor to behave similarly to other editors: if the edited file changes outside the IDE, I want the proper dialog window to be displayed and the document reloaded (if needed).

The `IVsPersistDocData` interface contains methods `IsDocDataReloadable` and `ReloadDocData`, but during debugging, they were never called in this scenario.

There is a combination of `IVsFileChangeEx` and `IVsFileChangeEvents` interfaces, but reaction to changing files outside the IDE seems to be so generic, that I guess I shouldn't need to manually monitor the edited file. Or should I?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that there actually is no automatic mechanism for doing that and using `IVsFileChangeEx` and `IVsFileChangeEvents` seems to be the only solution.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2005/11/01/487721.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsFileChangeEx.aspx